# STL algorithm all or any function?

Tags: c++, stl

Is there anything approximating Haskell's all or any functions as part of the STL?  If not, is the below a good implementation (I noticed the sgi STL performed partial specialization if the iterators were random access, though I have not bothered with this)?

```
template <typename InputIterator, typename Predicate>
inline bool all(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Predicate pred) {
  while (first != last) {
    if (!pred(*first)) {
      return false;
    }
    ++first;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Similarly, how would this best be transformed to iterate two sequences, and return true where a BinaryPredicate returns true for all, and false otherwise?  I know this is relatively trivial, but it seems like this should be provided by algorithm, and I want to make sure I'm not overlooking something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are not `all` or `any` algorithms in C++ currently, but C++0x adds `std::all_of` and `std::any_of` algorithms to the C++ standard library.  Your implementation may support these already.

Since both of these algorithms need to test every element in the range (at least until they find a match or mismatch), there isn't any reason to specialize them for different types of iterators:  the performance when used with forward iterators should be the same as the performance when used with random access iterators.

Your implementation of `all` is fine; the Visual C++ `all_of` implementation is effectively the same, except that it uses a for loop instead of a while loop.

> how would this best be transformed to iterate two sequences, and return true where a BinaryPredicate returns true for all, and false otherwise?

This is what `std::equal` does.  You'll need to check the sizes of the ranges first to ensure that they are of the same size.

Comment: I shall also point toward `std::mismatch`, which returns a pair of iterators indicating the first difference in the two sequences.

Answer (score 5):

This looks almost equivalent to `std::find_if` with the predicate inverted to me.

Comment: +1: Why reinvent the wheel here when we already have a perfectly good wheel?

Comment: @John Dibling: Because I want to build my blue wheel here as nobody else can build a good wheel. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use std::find_if like, which returns `Iterator last` if the predicate returns false for all elements, otherwise it returns the element that it returns true for.

```
Iterator it = std::find_if (container.begin (), container.end (), predicate);
if (it != container.end ())
    // One of them doesn't match
```

Comment: Instead of "one of them doesn't match," it should be "one of them matches," right?  You can implement `any` this way, but you would need to negate the predicate to implement `all` this way.

Comment: std::find_if() is a good candidate for an alternate implementation (one that I would prefer if I was writing the functions), but it is not equivalent in that it doesn't return a Boolean result, as apparently the Haskell functions do.

Answer (score -1):

How about foreach from BOOST ? it's not STL but available for any platform.

Comment: Doesn't do what OP wants.  FOREACH iterates over the entire sequence.  OP wants to iterate over the sequence until something is evaluated as true, then stop.