# How do I convert this line of Python into C++?

Tags: python, c++

Sorry if this is a bit of a simple question, but I'm really struggling to convert this last line of code from a Python program into C++

the line of code is:

```
if all(x % k == 0 for k in range(1, 21))
```

Which is basically meant to check if X is evenly divisible by all of the numbers 1-20.

Does anyone know how I can convert this?

Edit: Some context around the program:

```
    x = 0
    while(x != -1):
        x = x + 20
        if all(x % k == 0 for k in range(1, 21)):
            print(x)
            return 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559845/stl-algorithm-all-or-any-function

Comment: well, you could convert it to one operation: `if x % 232792560 == 0` (232792560 is least common multiple of [1..20]).

Comment: Google algorithm all gives you http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/all_of/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 10; // or whatever...

    // create vector of 20 ints
    std::vector<int> range(20);
    // fill vector with increasing numbers, starting at 1
    std::iota(range.begin(), range.end(), 1);

    // do the testing
    bool result = std::all_of(range.begin(), range.end(), [x] (int k) { return x % k == 0; });

    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That is closer to what python really does under the hood, but is quite inefficient.

Comment: Same mistake as below. I think... 21 should be excluded.

Comment: @juanchopanza Why would it be "inefficient"?

Comment: @Rapptz It is creating a vector when there is no need for one. Doing this doesn't really make the code easier to follow or maintain.

Answer (score 3):

One easy way is to implement write your own loop:

```
bool test_something(int x)
{
  for (int i = 1; i < 21; ++i)
  {
    if (x % i != 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool test_div(long num){
  for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++){   
     if(num % i != 0){
        return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
}

int main(){
    int count = 0;
    long number = 0;
    while(1){
        number+=1;
        if (test_div(number)){
            count+=1;
            cout << "Find " << count << "th match number: " << number << endl;
            if(count == 10)
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Find 1th match number: 232792560
Find 2th match number: 465585120
Find 3th match number: 698377680
Find 4th match number: 931170240
Find 5th match number: 1163962800
Find 6th match number: 1396755360
Find 7th match number: 1629547920
Find 8th match number: 1862340480
Find 9th match number: 2095133040
Find 10th match number: 2327925600
```

Check with python:

```
In [1]: x = 2327925600
In [2]: all(x % k == 0 for k in range(1, 21))
Out[3]: True
```